# Bat file failing to successfully deploy SCCM?

Tags: batch-file, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, sccm, sccm-2007

I have deployed a bat file to a device using the with file name as the install line e.g. app.bat

It is a simple one line piece of code:

for /d %I in ("C:\ProgramData\theapp*") do "%~I\theapp.exe"

But this fails to deliver and I I receive a generic 1006 error. Could this issue be realted to the bat file itself?

Comment: in batch files, % symbols must be doubled where `For` variables are concerned. So `%%l` or `%%~l` instead of `%l` or `%~l`

Comment: In the future, please read the help file for a command before asking a question.  The eighth line of the help file says: **To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.**

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `PowerShell` tags when there is no reference to Powershell in your question nor is there any PowerShell code in your question.